# GoogleChrome-fullscreen issue

Tags: javascript

I tried with different options for automatically making a page full screen using javascript

1. I tried with the window.open("index.html","","fullscreen=yes,location=no, cursor=none");
2. I tried with the Native FullScreen JavaScript API- It only works on a button click or any other events , but I need to make the page automatically open on fullscreen.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It's technically a security issue if you could do it.

Answer (score 2):

> ...I need to make the page automatically open on fullscreen

You can't, and for good reason. That's why the fullscreen API (and `window.open`, typically) only works in response to a user event. It's *by design* to prevent web pages from hijacking the user's workspace.